# C++ no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, constructor, c++-cli

I have some experience with C# but C++ syntax and program construction makes some problems.
I am using Visual C++ 2008. Firstly why is there this error?:

> 1>......\Form1.h(104) : error C2512:
>   'Cargame::Car' : no appropriate default constructor available

Secondly, why is not this line possible? //System::Drawing::Color color;

> error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'color' in an unmanaged 'Car'

Form1.h contains:

```
namespace Cargame {
    using namespaces bla bla bla

    class Car;

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    Car* car;

        protected:
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        { delete components; }
    }

SOME MORE AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED CODE

    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 panel1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
                 car = new Car();
                 //car->draw();
             }
    };
}
```

Contents of Car.h:

```
class Car
{
private:
        int speed;
        //System::Drawing::Color color;

public:
        Car();
};
```

Contents of Car.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <math.h>

//extern TForm1 *Form1;

Car::Car()
{
        speed = 0;
}

void Car::draw()
{
//implementation
}
```

Comment: That isn't C++, sorry. ('public ref class'...  No, definitely not C++).  Did you mean C++/CLI, or some other variant?

Comment: I just took Windows Forms Application in New Project...
I have 0 experience with C++

Comment: In which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual C++ 2008 Express and
I am not using 2010 because it has some problems with Intellisense

Comment: You are starting with C++/CLI, not the easiest start if you don't know much C++.

Comment: Do you include the header for 'car.h" anywhere? (Other than in car.cpp), I suspect you are getting confused by precompiled headers. (That's the stdafx.h thing), another visual-studio-ism.

Comment: Well, I don't have problems to write C++ console applications (lied a little about the 0 experience), but now I have to write this program with that Form and Visual C++.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve error C2512 you need to add:

```
#include "Car.h"
```

to Form1.h.

Answer (score 1):

Place the definition of a class `Car` in the same namespace as its forward declaration has been placed.

e.g.

Contents of Car.h:

```
namespace Cargame {
class Car
{
private:
        int speed;
        //System::Drawing::Color color;

public:
        Car();
};
}
```

Contents of Car.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <math.h>

//extern TForm1 *Form1;
using namespace Cargame;
Car::Car()
{
        speed = 0;
}

void Car::draw()
{
//implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The unmanaged code error is because you declared a unmanaged pointer, I think.

Try `Car ^ car` I think that is the right syntax.

And you need to define your class as `ref class Car`